Interpolation Control for doing Timing Recovery in FPGAs
I intend to make a timing recovery circuit on an FPGA and for that I have to make synthesizable models of Xilinx Blocks for Interpolation Control (Module-1 Counter based)
in Simulink.
I have made Simulink block diagram for these
Interpolation Control
And MATLAB code for it is
function [Underflow, mu] = Interpolation_ctrl(Delta)
W = 16; % accumulator wordlength
F = 15; % accumulator fraction length

persistent delay1 Regtemp;  
if isempty(delay1)
    delay1  = fi(0,1,W,F);
    Regtemp = fi(0,1,W,F);
end

mask = fi(1-2^(-F),1,W,F);

counter = bitand(mask,delay1)-Delta-fi(0.5,1,W,F); % decrementing counter
% if delay1 is a nonnegative number,
% then mod(delay1,1) equals the fractional part of delay1

if counter < 0
        % if this is true
    Underflow = true;
    Regtemp = bitshift(bitand(mask,delay1),1);     
else
    Underflow = false;
end

mu = Regtemp;

% Update delay buffer
% delay1 = counter;
if counter<0
    delay1 = fi(counter+1,1,W,F); %make sure delay1 is nonnegative
else
    delay1 = fi(counter,1,W,F);
end
% If both current and previous enable signals are 0, skip current sample
% and keep the delayed signals unchanged. (Bit stripping)
delayStrobe = strobe;

This model doesn't generate correct underflow or fractional delay and I don't know why. Does anyone have similar simulink model or any input on how to fix the shortcomings ?
Additionally, how do you decide the delays in system generator models ? Maybe my delays are wrong.
